# Where is the voltage regulator on a Honda Wave 125cc?

Tags: electrical, honda, motorcycle

Where can I find the voltage regulator on my Honda Wave 125cc?

I need to replace it with a new one so that my head lights will be in good condition and work well.

Comment: Welcome to SE Mechanics! Can you tell us the year of your bike. Also it would help if you could tell us more about the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: What year is your motorcycle?

Answer (score 1):

there are a couple of places it could be on your scooter depending on the year. If you take off the body fairings/plastics, the voltage regulator also called the RR can be found amid a cluster of wires either on the side of the scooter, near the front forks or the "tree" or (as I worked on a couple) underneath the seat inside the body (there should be a panel you can pop off). The easiest way to find it is by location your wire harness and following it down through the bike, it should end in a couple of 6 pin or 5 pin connectors and one of them will be connected to the voltage regulator, it looks like a metal rectangle with little metal fins.